# Spring 2.5 or 3.0

Tags: spring

I have a book called "Spring Recipes" which seems very good so far, but does not cover Spring 3.0. Should I continue with this book or hunt down a resource/s which covers Spring 3.0 and start from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for the big picture you don't necessarily need a book on Spring 3.0. If you are happy with your current book, keep using it. Once you've read through one book on Spring and have the basic concepts, you'll be ready to take on the reference documentation on the springframework.org website. You can get the descriptions of what changed with 3.0 and get more in-depth details about how Spring works.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense. I was leaning that way and your answer seals it. I really get a lot of help from SO for mostly specific but sometimes not so specific technical questions. Great site.